# Cropping out points from an array list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

crop: has parameters that are two Points in the Cloud. One of these two points is a bottom corner, and the other a diagonally across top corner of a rectangle. Crop will remove all points outside this rectangle from the Cloud much like you would crop an image. The crop method must deal with two input points on a horizontal or vertical line segment, in which case all points not on the line segment are removed, and it must deal with two equal Points p1 and p2, in which case all Points but p1 are removed from the Cloud.

For example, if the two input Points are (0.0,0,0) and (1.0,1.0), all Points outside the square delimited by (0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), and (0.0,1.0) are removed, but if the two input Points are (0.0,0,0) and (0.0,1.0), all Points outside the line segment delimited by (0.0,0.0), and (0.0,1.0) are removed.

I'm having a hard time approaching this logically.

```
public void crop(Point p1, Point p2) {
    Point left = points.get(0);
    Point right = points.get(1);
    Point top = points.get(2);
    Point bottom = points.get(3);
    // Point []rectangle2D = {p1,p2};
    Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(p1.getX(), p1.getY(),
            p2.getX(), p2.getY());
    if (p1.getX() == p2.getX() || p1.getY() == p2.getY()) {
        points.add(p1); // checks if equal
    }

    // checks if its in the square;
    if (left.getX() > p1.getX() && left.getY() > p1.getY()
            && left.getX() < p2.getX() && left.getY() < p2.getY()) {
        points.add(left);
    } else {
        points.remove(left);
    }
    if (right.getX() > p1.getX() && right.getY() > p1.getY()
            && right.getX() < p2.getX() && right.getY() < p2.getY()) {
        points.add(right);
    } else {
        points.remove(right);
    }
    if (top.getX() > p1.getX() && top.getY() > p1.getY()
            && top.getX() < p2.getX() && top.getY() < p2.getY()) {
        points.add(top);
    } else {
        points.remove(top);
    }
    if (bottom.getX() > p1.getX() && bottom.getY() > p1.getY()
            && bottom.getX() < p2.getX() && bottom.getY() < p2.getY()) {
        points.add(bottom);
    } else {
        points.remove(bottom);
    }

    // checks the line coordinates

    if (p1.getX() == top.getX() && p1.getY() < top.getY()
            && top.getY() < bottom.getY() || p1.getX() < top.getX()
            && top.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == top.getY()) {
        points.add(top);
    }
    if (p1.getX() == right.getX() && p1.getY() < right.getY()
            && left.getY() < right.getY() || p1.getX() < right.getX()
            && right.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == right.getY()) {
        points.add(right);
    }
    if (p1.getX() == top.getX() && p1.getY() < top.getY()
            && left.getY() < top.getY() || p1.getX() < top.getX()
            && top.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == top.getY()) {
        points.add(top);
    }
    if (p1.getX() == bottom.getX() && p1.getY() < bottom.getY()
            && left.getY() < bottom.getY() || p1.getX() < bottom.getX()
            && bottom.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == bottom.getY()) {
        points.add(bottom);
    }

}
```

or

```
    Point left = points.get(0);
    Point right = points.get(1);
    Point top = points.get(2);
    Point bottom = points.get(3);
    // Point []rectangle2D = {p1,p2};
    if(left.getX() > p1.getX()){
        points.remove(left);
    }
    if(left.getY() > p1.getY()){
        points.remove(left);
    }
    if(left.getX() < p1.getX()){
        points.remove(left);
    }
    if(left.getY() < p1.getY()){
        points.remove(left); 
    }

    //checks right

    if(right.getX() > p1.getX()){
        points.remove(right);
    }
    if(right.getY() > p1.getY()){
        points.remove(right);
    }
    if(right.getX() < p1.getX()){
        points.remove(right);
    }
    if(right.getY() < p1.getY()){
        points.remove(right);
    }
    //checks top

    if(top.getX() > p1.getX()){
        points.remove(top);
    }
    if(top.getY() > p1.getY()){
        points.remove(top);
    }
    if(top.getX() < p1.getX()){
        points.remove(top);
    }
    if(top.getY() < p1.getY()){
        points.remove(top);
    }

    //checks bottom
    if(bottom.getX() > p1.getX()){
        points.remove(bottom);
    }
    if(bottom.getY() > p1.getY()){
        points.remove(bottom);
    }
    if(bottom.getX() < p1.getX()){
        points.remove(bottom);
    }
    if(bottom.getY() < p1.getY()){
        points.remove(bottom);
    }
    //checking lines
    if(p1.getX() == left.getX() && p1.getY() < left.getY() && left.getY() < p2.getY() ||
        p1.getX()  < left.getX() && left.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == left.getY()){
        points.add(left);
    }

    if(p1.getX() == right.getX() && p1.getY() < right.getY() && right.getY() < p2.getY() ||
            p1.getX()  < right.getX() && right.getX() < p2.getX() && p1.getY() == right.getY()){
            points.add(right);
        }
    if(p1.getX() == top.getX() && p1.getY() < top.getY() && top.getY() < p2.getY() ||
            p1.getX()  < top.getX() && top.getX() < top.getX() && p1.getY() == top.getY()){
            points.add(top);
        }
    if(p1.getX() == bottom.getX() && p1.getY() < bottom.getY() && bottom.getY() < p2.getY() ||
            p1.getX()  < bottom.getX() && bottom.getX() < bottom.getX() && p1.getY() == bottom.getY()){
            points.add(bottom);
        }

    if(p1.getX() == p2.getX() || p1.getY() == p2.getY()){
        points.add(p2);
    }
```

Comment: can you break down your question in readable format plz?

Comment: I would imagine you could create a `Rectangle2D` and use it's `contains(Point)` method to trim of those points to fall outside it's range

Comment: what do you mean by saying (0.0,0,0)?

Comment: so you want to ignore all points which are not in the range (0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), and (0.0,1.0)?

Comment: Yes ignore the points that are outside if that range or the range of points implemented

Comment: Sounds like you want a range search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching

Comment: The range of points outside the those set if points are cropped out ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using geometric logic, for more understanding try on a paper using quadrants and sample points.

assume if the parameter (x1,y1), and (x2,y2)

to check for point (a,b) whether inside the square, 
condition `(a>x1 && b>y1) And (a<x2 && b<y2)`. 
If satisfies condition it is inside the Square else not.

assume if the parameter (x1,y1), and (x2,y2) [and x1==x2 OR y1==y2]

to check for point (a,b) whether within a line, 
condition `(x1==a && y1<b<y2) OR (x1<a<x2 && y1==b)`

it worked for me, to find whether a point is within a triangle of given vertices.

hope this is helpful

Comment: I've tried This and if I could, I would show you my code but I'm in car for hours. if statements. For some reason it's not fully working. Could you provided and example of your ifs so I can compare

Comment: @user3781657 I posted up my answer so hope it helps what you want to do. could you please let me know if it helped you? thank you

Comment: @KickButtowski It needs to be something like

Comment: what? did my answer help?

Comment: i needs to be something like i edited my code for example if i have the points in the cloud  [(3.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0), (1.5,1.5), (3.0,0.0)] and i pass in points p1 and p4 so 3.0,1.0 and 3.0,0.0 it will crop out all points not in that range so the answer would be [(3.0,1.0), (3.0,0.0)]

Comment: @KickButtowski http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460886/croping-points-in-an-arraylist-in-java?noredirect=1#comment37855167_24460886

Comment: I'm out take a look at it later

Comment: thanks for offering to look @KickButtowski and no becasue it was not the right logic to the problem

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this sample code to give you some ideas. Hope I was able to understand your question.

```
    double[][] legalRange = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0}};
    double[] point = { 91.0, 0.0};

    for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
        boolean resutl = (point[i] >= 0.0) && (point[i] < 1.1);
        if(!resutl) {
            System.out.println("(" + point[0] + "," + point[1] + ") not in the range");
            return; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("(" + point[0] + "," + point[1] + ") in the range");
```

output:

```
(91.0,0.0) not in the range
```